# Holding event fired only after click

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I need to use `Holding` event on my `ListView` to enable items reordering, and I can't use `RightTapped` because it will fire only after pointer release, which is not what the user is expecting.

The problem here is that `Holding` event fires only after I click on the item once. After that click it works fine, before that click it doesn't fire, no matter how long I keep it pressed.

The code is actually really simple:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Padding="5,10,10,10"
          BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
          BorderBrush="Black"
          IsHoldingEnabled="True"                                      
          Holding="UIElement_OnHolding"

...

private void UIElement_OnHolding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.HoldingState != HoldingState.Started) return;
    e.Handled = true;
    App.ViewModelLocator.MainPageViewModel.IsReorderingEnabled = true;
}
```

I'm testing the app using the emulator, and I really don't understand the reason of this behavior.

Is this a known issue which I'm not aware of? Can you please help me fixing this?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried to set Grid's Background to *Transparent*?

Comment: It seems to be working with `Transparent` background, but I can't use it because my entries need a different background. Do you know why it doesn't work with a different background? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: You can probably use any other background. They key here is I think that when you have no background declared for the grid, then hit testing will work only for elements that are inside not for the whole gird.

Comment: Wait. I have the issue if I'm using a background, while it works with background set as `Transparent`.

Comment: Can you show the whole datatemplate and listview/its style?